# Change currency from Yahoo! Finance's historical data

Tags: bash, data-conversion, yahoo-finance, qlikview, currency-exchange-rates

I was asked to make a DSS (using QlikView) as a task for a university course in computational finance and it is suggested to implement a geographic dimension for the equities in a portfolio.

The historical data comes (as .csv files) from Yahoo! Finance, but for foreign equities/stock exchange, I also get them in foreign currencies!
As long as I'm supposed to plot them (if not something more), it makes sense to me that, in order to be comparable, they also have to have the same currency.

So… I'm looking for a simple and effective way to get those data without being crazy with historical currency changes. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: P.S.: As for now, I've thinked to write a bash script that, given the historical currency changes (if available) and a .csv file, generates a new .cvs file or the same with an added column; but that goes *very* beyond the purpose of the task/course.

Comment: Can you post (or give a link) to some sample data?

Comment: @StefanStoichev Sure, just click the "Download to Spreadsheet" [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=CAT&a=00&b=1&c=2000&d=00&e=1&f=2015&g=d) and suppose I want them in Euro.

Comment: Can you check it the qvw file from the link is the result you need?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOVVlSOGNQU1h2Ync/view?usp=sharing